# login in div without refreshing

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a loginout.php like:

```
<?php if($isLoggedIn) { ?>
<form method="POST" action="" name="logoutForm" id="logoutForm" accept-charset='UTF-8'>
    <input type='hidden' name='submitted' id='submitted' value='1'/>
    <input type="submit" name="logout" value="Logout" />
</form>
<? } else { ?>
<form method="POST" action="" name="loginForm" id="loginForm" accept-charset='UTF-8'>
    <input type='hidden' name='submitted' id='submitted' value='1'/>
    Email:    <input type="text"     name="usr" /><br />
    Password: <input type="password" name="pw"  /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" />
</form>
<? }?>
```

a div like

```
<div id="loginLogoutDiv"></div>
```

and also jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#loginLogoutDiv').load('loginout.php');
    $('#loginForm, #logoutForm').live('submitted', function() {
        $.post('loginout.php', $(this).serialize(), function (
        data, textStatus) {
            $('#loginLogoutDiv').html(data);
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

What is wrong if pressing the Login button, then whole page is refreshed that i don't want?

Thank you

Comment: There's no `submitted` event, its `submit`

Answer (score 2):

Replace:

```
$('#loginForm, #logoutForm').live('submitted', function() { 
    ...
```

With

```
$('#loginForm, #logoutForm').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    ...
```

so that you get...

```
$(function(){
    $('#loginLogoutDiv').load('loginout.php');
    $('#loginForm, #logoutForm').submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.post('loginout.php', $(this).serialize(), function (
        data, textStatus) {
            $('#loginLogoutDiv').html(data);
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The event you want to attach to is called `submit`, not `submitted`.

Also, check your console for errors in your javascript — if your script is terminated due to an error before it can `return false` in your `onsubmit` handler, the default behavior will not be prevented.

Comment: Hi, can you give a whoe code. I have also header('Refresh: 1; url='.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); that is used in a succesful loging. How to put to show a logout-form after logging?

Comment: Other answers to your question already include complete code. The refresh header will not do what you expect, since it is returned in response to an AJAX request, and not for the page displayed in the browser. I don't understand your question about the logout form, but it seems beyond the scope of this question and you should probably post a new question for it.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way (mean JS):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#loginLogoutDiv').load('loginout.php');
    $('#loginForm, #logoutForm').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // this will prevent the page to really do a submit
        $.post('loginout.php', $(this).serialize(), function (
        data, textStatus) {
            $('#loginLogoutDiv').html(data);
        });
    });
});
```

If You need to use `live()`, this should do it:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#loginLogoutDiv').load('loginout.php');
    $('#loginForm, #logoutForm').live('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // this will prevent the page to really do a submit
        $.post('loginout.php', $(this).serialize(), function (
        data, textStatus) {
            $('#loginLogoutDiv').html(data);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for responses 
$('#loginForm,#logoutForm').submit(function(event) {
..
does not work.
$('#loginForm, #logoutForm').live('submitted', function() { .. works in my system.